# Stored Procedure Stuck when Linked Server Failed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a `Linked Server` (to Oracle Server) on SQL Server 2016. I then create a `Stored Procedure` to select the linked server like so.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestSelectData
AS
SELECT *
FROM LinkedServer..TestUser.TestTable
```

On normal connection, it run successfully. And the `Stored Procedure` return the expected result. But when the connection to the linked server is broken (wrong password, wrong IP, etc), the `Stored Procedure` didn't raise error and run forever.

I tried to change the linked server option for `connect timeout` and `query timeout` to 900 (15 minutes). But it still not raising an error after 15 minutes.

I tried to run only the `SELECT` without `Stored Procedure`, it raise an error like so.

```
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LinkedServer".
```

So, why it raise an error when using `SELECT` only, but run forever in `Stored Procedure`?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe creating procedure `WITH RECOMPILE` can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I seen something interesting on MSDN, regarding Remote Stored Procedure.

Quote from MSDN [Handling Errors in Server-to-Server Remote Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191515(v=sql.105))

- > When a statement abort error occurs, the statement that caused the
  >   error is terminated, but the execution of the remote stored procedure 
  >   or batch continues.

Also found,

> If SET XACT_ABORT is ON in the local server, the setting is propagated
>   to the linked server. All statement and batch abort errors in the
>   remote stored procedure are converted to batch abort errors in the
>   local server. Therefore, execution of the batch or stored procedure
>   that called the remote stored procedure is terminated together with
>   the remote stored procedure.

So, you may to need impose a connection level setting in your stored procedure i.e `SET XACT_ABORT Is ON`. And might also need a try catch block.

You can find detailed information on MSDN.. Give a look on it.